Expo development build restarts once foregrounded
I haven't been able to find anything regarding this topic, so bear with me.
I've recently upgraded to SDK 50. Before the upgrade, everything worked as expected.
When I background my app (dev build) and then proceed to foreground it by either tapping on the app's icon or tapping on a received notification, the app opens up, the splash screen is briefly shown and then it just restarts.
This bug(?) isn't reproducible in the preview and production builds of the application, however this makes testing push notifications and actions dispatched from event listeners (such as AppState) impossible. What's going on here?
I've confirmed that this can be reproduced with a basic getting started application. Just start the app up (after creating a dev build), background the app, find the app's icon and then click on it.

Did you manage to find a way around this or figure out whats happening? I have the same issue

Instead of backgrounding the app and then tapping the app icon to open it, press the recent apps key and reopen the app from there. Best I could do
